# Problems about gmapping under the environment： ROS(hydro)+turtlebot2+rplidar

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, rplidar, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am really sorry to trouble everyone, and please forgive me for my poor English. But I really face some problems that I can't solve them.

I want to replace the Kinect with the rplidar laser device while gmapping, I fixed the rplidar in the middle of the turtlebot2, I installed the rplidar driver, and I wrote the gmapping launch file.

There's a problem in my map, unfortunately I don't know how to describe this problem in English, I want to upload some map pictures, but I am not qualified to upload images, so I upload my map result pictures to my Baidu network disk    :[TheGmappingResultPicture](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sj6snpF)
I hope you can visit this website..

And there is another question that I want to disturbe everyone, I tried to follow this method:[How to crate a map with gmapping and hokuyo laser](http://answers.ros.org/question/173122/how-to-crate-a-map-with-gmapping-and-hokuyo-laser/)  However I can't found the folder `turtlebot_navigation/config`, but I really want to know what's the difference between these two file:`turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/gmapping.launch.xml` and `turtlebot_navigation/config/gmapping.launch.xml`

**Once again express my gratitude! Thank you very much!!**

Below is my gmapping launch file:

```
<launch>   
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_base_broadcaster" args="0.00 0 0.24 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
  <include file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/rplidar.launch" />
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find rplidar_ros)/rviz/slam.rviz" />
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="scan_topic" value="scan" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="throttle_scans" value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_publish_period" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="maxUrange" value="6"/>
    <param name="sigma" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
    <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
    <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
    <param name="srr" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="srt" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="str" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="stt" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="temporalUpdate" value="-1.0"/>
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="particles" value="30"/>
    <param name="xmin" value="-50.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-50.0"/>
    <param name="xmax" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
    <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199818/problems-about-gmapping-under-the-environment%EF%BC%9A-ros(hydro)+turtlebot2+rplidar/) by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you already solve the problem. If not you can find [here](http://geduino.blogspot.it/2015/04/gmapping-and-rplidar.html) how to make RPLidar works with GMapping.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2015-04-17**:
Thank you so much. And I am sorry that  these days I am busy and I forgot to close this question.